# Removing digits from a file

Tags: python

I have a file of the form:

```
car1 auto1 automobile1 machine4 motorcar1
bridge1 span5
road1 route2
```

But I want to remove the integers so that my file looks like:

```
car auto automobile machine motorcar
bridge span
road route
```

I am trying to read the file character by character, and if a character is a digit, skip it. But I am printing them in a new file. How can I make changes in the input file itself?

Comment: show some more code examples of what you tried? like can you already read in the file, and get it so that you got strings like car1 etc? (and is this homework?)

Comment: I am trying to read the file character by character, and if a character is a digit, skip it. But i am printing them in a new file. How can i make changes in the input file itself?

Comment: @naka, It would be helpful to post that information in your original question, instead of in the comments.

Comment: You'll have to write over your file with the new lines, see @Joel Cornett's answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html):

```
import re
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input("your_file.txt", inplace=True):
    print re.sub("\d+", "", line),
```

note: fileinput is a nice module for working with files.

Edit: for better performance/less flexibility you can use:

```
import fileinput
import string

for line in fileinput.input("your_file.txt", inplace=True):
    print line.translate(None, string.digits),
```

For multiple edits/replaces:

```
import fileinput
import re

for line in fileinput.input("your_file.txt", inplace=True):
    #remove digits
    result = ''.join(i for i in line if not i.isdigit())
    #remove dollar signs
    result = result.replace("$","")
    #some other regex, removes all y's
    result = re.sub("[Yy]+", "", result)
    print result,
```

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary That's right, fixed. Forgot about print doing that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helps. Can I use more than one replacement policy in re.sub() function? Like here i am replacing digits by blanks. But what if I want to, in addition, replace a special character with something else? calling another re.sub("$","",line) would print another line in that case

Comment: hi Naka, yes, that is correct, but if you need several replacements try the edited version above.

Comment: `str.join` is almost 4 times slower than regex, and regex is almost 50 times slower than `str.translate`.

Answer (score 3):

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f1, open('output.txt', 'w') as f2:
    f2.write("".join([c for c in f1.read() if not c.isdigit()]))
```

Comment: do you mean `string = [character for character in f.read() if not character.isdigit()]` and `f.write(''.join(string))` ?  (ps: `str` is a protected name in python.)

Comment: I would use `with`, as it's much more pythonic than the `f = open()...f.close()` pattern.

Comment: @JoelCornett: what about that? :)

Comment: Much better :P I'm not sure about opening 2 different handles for the same file at the same time though. Is it possible that it could lead to unexpected behavior based on when the OS decides to do things?

Comment: here I have two handlers.

Comment: Oh, never mind, now that I've thought about it, this wouldn't be a problem. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    data = ''.join(i for i in f.read() if not i.isdigit())

with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Comment: You can also use `str.tranlate`, it is way faster than both regex and your approach.

Answer (score 1):

Use `with` to read/write the file and the `str.translate` function to replace the digits with an empty string. See here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate

```
with open('file', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
data = data.translate(None, '0123456789')
with open('file', 'w') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fpath = '/path/to/your/file'
outpath = '/path/to/your/output/file'
f = open(fpath)
content = f.read()

new_content = ''

for letter in content:
    try:
        int(letter)
    except:
        new_content += letter

outf = open(outpath, 'w')
outf.write(new_content)
outf.close()
f.close()
```

Comment: That's not very Pythonic. Why not use `with` and String operations?

Comment: You are right, I just looked at the other answers and I have half the mind to delete my own :D

Comment: But then the guy who asked the question may not really understand if it is too complex

Comment: than he should ask why the other solutions work, and than we can explain more about it, and why the other solution is more pythonic, (if he has questions at the level of separating strings, i guess the concept of "pythonic" code is new to him as well, so maybe leave this example as how it could be done, and than the other examples as how the pythonic version of it is

Answer (score 0):

I used this method for a million row dataset recently. Repeating yourself but quick and simple.

```
import regex as re

filename = r'/path/to/file/textfile.txt'

string = open(filename).read()

cleaned = re.sub('1', '', string)
cleaned = re.sub('2', '', cleaned)
cleaned = re.sub('3', '', cleaned)
cleaned = re.sub('4', '', cleaned)
cleaned = re.sub('5', '', cleaned)
cleaned = re.sub('6', '', cleaned)
cleaned = re.sub('7', '', cleaned)
cleaned = re.sub('8', '', cleaned)
cleaned = re.sub('9', '', cleaned)
cleaned = re.sub('0', '', cleaned)

open(filename, 'w').writelines(cleaned)
```