# Remove Punctuation, output remaining text-Python 3 Function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to run this file through my function and then output the remaining text once the integers, or numbers are removed. Below is my python code:

```
theFile=open("home/filepath/file",'rt', encoding= 'latin-1').read()
words= the_file.split()

def replace_numbers(words):
    new_words=[]
    for word in words:
        new_word= re.sub(" \d+", " ", word)
        if new_word !='':
            new_words.append(new_word)
    return new_words

replace_numbers(words)
```

Here is some sample text in the file:

> soccerfif@yahoo.com 366-44-4444 Jezos was born Jeffrey Preston Jorgensen on January 12, 1964, also 5 and 4"

I want the output to be:

> soccerfif@yahoo.com 366-44-4444 Jezos was born Jeffrey Preston Jorgensen on January 12, 1964, also  and

So basically removes all integers from the text file. Simple.

Is there a way to return the results of removing all the numbers in the file and then outputting whats left. As of right now, the output is just []. I know the issue is probably in the if `new_word != ''`: section but I can't seem to find the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing digits from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693318/removing-digits-from-a-file)

Comment: Please make this a complete question by showing a few lines of sample input data, along with the expected output.

Comment: `words = the file.split()` should be `words = theFile.split()`

Comment: that was a typo

Comment: I'd like to point out that 12, 1964, 366, 44, and 4444 are *all* integers. You don't appear to want to remove all integers from the file, just...single digit integers? Please be more precise.

Comment: Also the title says "remove punctuation" but then you talk about integers. Which is it?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to remove the parts that are *all* digits, you do not even need `re`. Just `split` and then keep everything that `not isdigit`.

```
>>> text = "soccerfif@yahoo.com 366-44-4444 Jezos was born Jeffrey Preston Jorgensen on January 12, 1964, also 5 and 4"
>>> [word for word in text.split() if not word.isdigit()]
['soccerfif@yahoo.com', '366-44-4444', 'Jezos', 'was', 'born', 'Jeffrey', 'Preston', 'Jorgensen', 'on', 'January', '12,', '1964,', 'also', 'and']
>>> ' '.join(_)
'soccerfif@yahoo.com 366-44-4444 Jezos was born Jeffrey Preston Jorgensen on January 12, 1964, also and'
```

Comment: Excellent and clean answer! What if I need to remove all digits or all characters? just to know

Comment: @Salam For removing all digits, just iterate chars, not words: `[c for c in text if not c.isdigit()]`. For removing all characters... well, `new_text = ""` should do, I guess?

Comment: How would you incorporate that in my code tho? With a text file?

Comment: @JamesDavinport Just put `the_file.split()` where I use `text.split()`