# Removing digits from each line of a file

Tags: python, string, loops

I wish to write a code in Python which reads each line from a txt and whilst doing so takes each digit from that sentence and stores it in an array. Simultaneously, takes that new word and stores that one in another array.

I have been trying permutation of the following code:

```py
while True:
    content=file.readline()
print (re.sub(pattern, '', content.file.readline())
```

with no success (Yes I do not have the array specified!! But if this loop does not work, what is the point of appending the content to an array?)

Comment: `content` is already a line from the file, why are you calling it again in the `re.sub`?  Also, if the `re.sub` is not in the while loop, then nothing will happen in this code, eventually the readline() will hit the end of the file, and return empty string forever

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing digits from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693318/removing-digits-from-a-file)

Comment: Please show a few sample lines from your file and what datastructures you expect to derive from those lines.

Comment: 122 dogs, 12cats45 in line one. Line two: 56sn89ails, 1b2a2n2a2n25s89

Comment: I thought that the print() command is in the while loop.

Comment: Also I do not want to remove the digit. I want identification, storage of the digits and storage of the strings once the digits have been removed. Therefore, using the arrays I am able to print the numbers in a separate file and the same with the words.

Comment: Give us an example and tell us what is the expected output

Comment: line one (122 dogs 12cats45) to store 122 in array and dogs in another array.

Comment: line two (56sn89ails, 1b2a2n2a2n25s89) to store 56, 89, 122222589 in the number array and the words snails, bananas in the word array. So when I ask print the content of the arrays it gives me all the stored number and the words.

Comment: Please click [edit] and put your sample input in your question, properly formatted, where it belongs so thst folks can see it without scrabbling around in the comments - which are liable to deletion at any time. Likewise, please add the expected result to your question. Both these things improve your odds of getting a better answer - and improve StackOverflow's usefulness. Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You can read each line from the file, using Regex get the list of all numbers or remove them.

```
import re

with open('file.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        numbers = re.findall(r'\d+',line)
        removed_numbers = re.sub(r'\d+','',line)
        
        print('numbers = ',numbers)
        print('removed numbers = ',removed_numbers)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
while True:
    content=file.readline()
    numbah = ''
    for (i,c) in enumerate(content):
        if c in {'1','2','3',..}:
              numbah += c
              content = content[:i]+content[i+1:]
    print(numbah)
    print(content)
```

havent tested but try something like this mb ?

edit : go through line char by char. if char is digit char, add the digit char to already memorized digit chars and remove from current line/ at the end you will have a variable with the number made up of the digits in the line ( numbah ) and in ( content ) the line with the digits removed

Comment: This returns this error:     if c in {'1','2','3',..}:
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: ofc, you have to complete it with the rest of the digits

Comment: also julie, try chatgpt

Comment: The numbers to be any number

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**